# Windows 7 when starting ubuntu black & blue striped screen after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, windows-7, virtualbox

I got a message saying that my version of ubuntu was obsolete so I clicked to update.  I have Windows 7 and run ubuntu in a Virtual Box vm.  When ubuntu tries to startup I get a screen with black & blue stripes and large black words that i can't read.

Comment: What is your version of Virtual Box? For Ubuntu 12.10 we need version 4.2.2. or later to support X.Org Server 1.13.